# Auto populate field in excel based off another column

Tags: excel, autocomplete, autofill

I have a pretty complex spreadsheet that I need to update for efficiency.  We have 5 columns that track Quality of 5 different parts, which together make 1 complete product.  The columns have a drop down menu where you can select a "value". These two values are "Accepted" & "Rejected".  We have another column, that tells us the status of the complete product.  If there was a single rejection in that row then the whole product needs to be rejected.  What we usually do is mark everything as accepted, then as we check the items we mark which item parts need to be rejected.  When we have a rejection we have to mark both the individual part and the whole product.

Here's my question:  Is there a way in Excel to make it so that if I mark one of the individual part columns as rejected, it will autofill the complete product column as rejected so the user doesnt have to worry about that part?  I need to be able to preserve the other 4 parts columns if need be though.

This may be confusing.  But I have provided a screengrab, hopefully it will help make sense of this.

Below is a link to a screenshot of an example spreadsheet:
http://i1335.photobucket.com/albums/w678/adamrakers/test_spreadsheet_zpsba56b243.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to offer an alternative:

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH("Rejected 1",$C2:$G2,0)),"Accepted","Rejected 1")
```

This would be more efficient, I believe, with a very large table - but the different is probably too small to make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

In cell B2

```
=IF(COUNTIF($C2:$G2,"Rejected 1")>0,"Rejected 1","Accepted")
```

Drag and drop in the entire column

Comment: im having trouble applying this formula.  Any insight on how to do this?

Comment: B2 is the first cell below "Final product". C2:G2 represents the first range below "Part 1" to "Part 5". Does that explain it?